# How to store videos on Google App Engine, without forms?

Tags: google-app-engine, video, store

Having recently stumbled across GAE, I understand that videos are usually uploaded using a form, and then stored as a blob.

Is there a way to do this without forms?

I want to use GAE as a back end for an android application, where videos from the android are uploaded to the GAE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have any way of transferring the bytes from the mobile client to the server, you can use the [Blobstore write API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to write the bytes to the Blobstore.

Comment: Okay, so on the phone I convert the video to bytes, transfer it to the server, where I can store the bytes as a blob?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am suggesting.

Comment: Any way you want it to.  The simplest way is to set up a servlet on GAE and just make an HTTP request to that servlet, with the bytes in the payload.  However, you'll likely want something more robust, since uploading video (over mobile networks, no less) is going to be very unreliable and slow.  You'll need something akin to an upload manager, supporting pausing, stopping, and continuing upload.  I don't know of a library that does this off of the top of my head, but there probably is one.